# How to test different "tables input" in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, junit, spring-data-jpa, mocking

I have a Java program that retrieves data from 2 tables and after a quick processing, stores the resulting data in 2 other tables.

Therefore, I need to test the global behavior of my code, so the first idea that came to my mind is to create a lot of small input tables, with 2 or 3 rows (just for the test) . And then perform the code throughout all these test-tables and compare with the expected results (which are also small tables created beforehand).
the problem is that I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You can use h2 database to run in-memory database deliberately for tests; here is a short tutorial on the topic - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Comment: so every autowired classes in my test class will be automaticaly connected to H2 database ?i mean in my test class i autowired a service layer , it will be connected to H2 ?

Comment: It's heavily depend on how does your service layer structured, but if it has jdbcTempater or jpa repositories, then the answer is yes, the connection will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial idea would overcomplicate things. I would just create exact copies of the tables with a _test suffix and perform the same operations for the test tables as I would perform for the real tables. After the operations are completed, compare the contents of your test tables content with your expectations and then empty them.

Assuming that your tables are called s1, s2 and d1, d2, respectively, let's create s1_test, s2_test, d1_test and d2_test for your tests. And then perform the following algorithm:

```
for tc of testcases
    initialize s1_test, s2_test
    perform tc.operations(s1_test, s2_test, d1_test, d2_test)
    compare contents of d1_test and d2_test with tc.expectations
    clear d1_test, d2_test
end for
```

Comment: what is "testcases" ?

Comment: @recoba78 testcases is the collection of your test cases. You do not necessarily want to perform a single test. You might have several possible inputs to test. In my pseudo-code, testcases symbolizes everything you intend to test. For example you might want to test a null value for a field in one case and a text in the other case.

Comment: s1_test and s2 _test are different from one testcase to another ?

Comment: @recoba78 they they the same table, but they can be reused. You can of course define separate tables if something makes it necessary, like schema differences. But if you 1. Do the actual test 2. Check the results 3. Clear the tables then you can reuse them for the next test.

Comment: i see , but in my case , reusing the same input tables is useless .In fact the whole point of my test is to test differents  inputs . so in the example above , s1_test and s2 test should be different from one testcase to another

Comment: @recoba78 I doubt it is useless. You should avoid the creation of unnecessary tables unless you have a **VERY** good reason not to avoid them. Having the same type of table **does not mean** that you can perform a single test case. I have the impression that you fundamentally misunderstand how testing should be performed. I would like to ask you for an example when you actually need to use different tables. So far, I'm far from convinced that flooding your database with tables is really necessary. Seems to be a subpar approach.

Comment: yes , as an example , s1 has a foreign key to s2, and for the two tables, consider that the row is either valid or not. and for example in the destination table d2 , we have the same columns as s2 and a new one that represent how many s1 rows are "pointing" toward s2 rows. so i want to test the case where a valid s1 row is pointing toward a valid s2 row  / two valid s1 row are pointing toward a non valid s2 row / two(valid and non valid) row of s2 ponting toward valid s1 row / etc... etc ..

Comment: @recoba78 what stops you from removing every row from your test tables after validating the results each time and filling them with new data for the new test? To me it seems obvious that for each test case 1. You hydrate your test tables with a certain set of inputs 2. You do the actual test 3. You check the results and store them somewheree 4. You clear your test tables to enable the next test case, which will be different. You need to keep your tables' number to the minimum that's still necessary, because if you overcomplicate it, then you will get into problems.

Comment: yes that's you're right , your solution is so much easier , you think it can be done using Junit ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221016/discussion-between-recoba78-and-lajos-arpad).